# css selector not giving the desired results

Tags: html, css, scrapy, css-selectors

I am at this page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Commonwealth_Games_medal_table

If I try following css selector in chrome console :

```
$('.wikitable.sortable.plainrowheaders tr[bgcolor],tr[style] td[align=left] a')
```

I get O/P : `a tag` as expected

However when I try :

```
$('.wikitable.sortable.plainrowheaders tr[style],tr[bgcolor] td[align=left] a')
```

I get O/P : `<tr bgolor='#CCCCFF'>` which is not what I am looking for.

I want `<a> tag` in both the cases. And I can see order of `tr[bgcolor],tr[style]` is making all the difference. Can somebody where I am going wrong?

Comment: If you want only the second part to match, why did you include the first one? And it seems your selectors in the question are confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write your code something like this

```
$('.wikitable.sortable.plainrowheaders tr[style] a, .wikitable.sortable.plainrowheaders tr[bgcolor] td[align=left] a')
```

You have to write " a" with every every query.

Also can you please tell do you want to select all anchors in the table ? Because the query you are using as of now, is only selecting one of the anchor tags.

To select all anchor tags use the following query

```
$('.wikitable.sortable.plainrowheaders tr td[align=left] a')
```

Basically the query you used

```
$('.wikitable.sortable.plainrowheaders tr[bgcolor],tr[style] td[align=left] a')
```

can be interpreted as 2 queries as follows

```
$('.wikitable.sortable.plainrowheaders tr[bgcolor]')

$('tr[style] td[align=left] a')
```

That is why you are getting <tr> tag in first and <a> tag in second

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Your suggestions worked. And yes, I am targeting only particular <a> tag because it helps me fetch 'Host country'.